# SQL - select a column data based on set of matching records

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

help me write a sql where i need to choose column 1 data of table 1 only when column 2 records match exactly the same with table 2

Ex:
Table1

```
Column1 Column2
A        1
A        2
A        3
B        1
B        2
B        3
B        4
```

Table 2

```
Column1 Column2
A        1
A        2
A        3
A        4
B        1
B        2
B        3
B        4
```

I need to see only B from Column 1 since column2 data of B exactly matches table 2.

Case where

Table 1
    Column1 Column2
    C        1
    C        2
    C        3
    C        5
Table 2 
    Column1 Column2
    C        1
    C        2
    C        3
    C        4

C shouldn't be considered though the no of records match but the records

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: I tried inner join but then i am seeing A as well since 1/2/3 are matching with table 2

Comment: Can you upload the query you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an outer `join` and aggregation:

```
select t2.column1
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.column1 = t1.column1 and t2.column2 = t1.column2
group by t2.column1
having count(*) = count(t1.column1);
```

The `having` clause ensures that all rows in the original data match.  This assumes that `column2` has no duplicate values for a given `column1` value in either table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe:

```
select distinct col1 from t1
where col1 not in
(select col1 from
   (
     select t2.col1,t2.col2
     from t2
     minus
     select t1.col1,t1.col2
     from t1
   )
 )
```

Not pretty. but seems to work.  [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/382b7/6)